# json_encode and JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE in PHP

Tags: php

i used this script to convert all data to json by using json_encode

```
$response = array();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","market");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  die ("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
$myData = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `item`");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $myData[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($myData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

when I used this script the result is empty.
I check the connection and query via write echo method inside while loop. the result written and not has problem in connection and query, because in each loop is give me the array.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $myData[] = $row;
        echo json_encode($myData, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

And i want just one array for all my data
I don't know where is the problem.

I hope my question is clear

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: try to echo just $myData after loop without json_encode, to debug if problem is with $myData (empty?? - I am not sure how this could happen if if your second example is working) or json_encode

Comment: I echo just $myData after loop with out json_encode, I debug this not ** Notice: Array to string conversion** and echo **Array** word

Comment: My bad, use var_dump($myData) or print_r($myData) instead. Error tells us that $myData is an array, but it could still be empty

Comment: **this result is from print_r** : Array ( [0] => Array ( [i_id] => 45 [i_name] => 2 [i_desc] => 2 [i_prush_pri] => 2 [i_unit] => 2 [i_img_name] => burger.jpg ) [1] => Array ... etc . **And this result from var_dump** array (size=15)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'i_id' => int 45
      'i_name' => string '2' (length=1)
      'i_desc' => string '2' (length=1)
      'i_prush_pri' => string '2' (length=1)
      'i_unit' => string '2' (length=1)
      'i_img_name' => string 'burger.jpg' (length=10)
  1 => ... etc

Comment: So it seems that you have some data there, albeit in some array of array form. But that still should encode it somehow, see php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php for examples. Does json_encode print it as empty json ([]) or it doesnt print anything(that would point to some error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death ) ?